# Volatile arraylist not acting as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile, concurrentmodification

I am writing a multi-threaded platform game.  One thread does the painting job, the other thread, runs the game logic.  I have an array-list that both threads need to access at the same time.  I am iterating over all the elements of the array-list in my paint thread, and in my other thread, i sometimes remove or add elements to the array-list.  I get a concurrent-modification-exception but i don't understand why because doesn't the  volatile keyword only allow one thread to access a variable at a time.

Here is an example of my problem

my arraylist

```
private volatile ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
```

my painting code

```
    for(Entity entity : entities)
    {
        if(entity!=null && entity.getX()>=xs-Block.WIDTH && entity.getX()<=xs+Main.WIDTH)
            g.drawImage(entity.getImage(), entity.getX()-getXs(), entity.getY(), entity.getWidth(), entity.getHeight(), null);
    }
```

my remove code

```
public void removeEntity(Entity e)
{
    entities.remove(e);
}
```

Comment: please post code if you have tried some

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. `volatile` keyword only guarantees you that any modifications to variable which is declared `volatile` will be seen to all of the threads.

You need to synchronize your code correctly or use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `volatile` use `Collections.synchronizedList(list);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector , which is synchronized .

[Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to
>   implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java
>   Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations,
>   Vector is synchronized.